# No overload for method 'Write' takes 2 arguments

Tags: c#, serial-port, arguments, overloading

I am having some trouble getting past this fault. Could you help?

```c#
int required = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);

serialPort1.Write("OUT0");
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
serialPort1.Write("ISET1:0.5");
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);

serialPort1.Write("VSET1:",required);
```

The last line returns an error for No overload for method 'Write' takes 2 arguments. I guess I understand what the error means, but can't think of a way around it?

Thanks

Comment: Thou shalt read the Documentation.

Comment: You really can't think of a way round it? Look at the previous times you use `Write`, and what is the difference?

Comment: I should point out - I've never coded in c# before!

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1050fs1h(v=vs.110).aspx -- if you specify a length (I guess that's what you're trying to do), you have to specific a starting position as well. I've never coded in c# before, either ;)

Answer (score 4):

Use string.Format.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx

```
serialPort1.Write(string.Format("VSET1:{0}", required));
```

It will take the second parameter and insert it where the {0} bracket is. You'll get the following.

```
VSET:sometexthere
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean:

```
serialPort1.Write("VSET1:" + required.ToString() );
```

Earlier you have:

```
serialPort1.Write("OUT0");
```

and there is no error.